# grails field level security - spring acl

Tags: grails, spring-security, acl

I am working on a project where we have requirement to provide field level access to users.

Example:

Suppose there is an entity named employee with several fields

The application should allow secure access at the field level of the entity.

According to the access user is allowed to edit / read the fields.

We have thought of an implementation using spring acl but it provides instance level security.

Could someone please let know an elegant way to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [fields plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/fields).

It allows you to control how individual fields are rendered.

You could implement a security check within each field's `_field.gsp` fragment, or you could override the plugin's taglib's `f:all` method and add a security check there if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the plugin for that, but you'd need to do some extra work. The ACL support in Spring Security basically lets you say "grant permission x on object instance y (of type "foo") with id z to person p". There is an example permissions class with standard instances like Read, Write, Admin, etc., but the underlying infrastructure only works with the numbers 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. so you can easily define your own permission types - they're really just mappings of human-readable names to numbers. You typically grant permissions on domain object instances, but under the hood the names of the domain classes are just strings, so you could store any type name there. And the ids can be any value, e.g. a number or a string.

You wouldn't be able to use the @PreAuthorize and @PostFilter annotations on service methods, but you can still query the ACL beans to see if, given a field or whatever you want, the currently authenticated user is allowed to perform some action.

Comment: That means that we would require to use the permissions for each field which in this case would be a read and edit option per field. I was thinking to have these permissions on the object and according to them modify the object and return the edited object back removing the inaccessible fields. For this we can create a custom evaluator and override the haspermissions method to implement this logic. But I am not sure if this is the right way to do it?  Also we had a discussion to have our own acl which we could use along with the spring acl to resolve the field level permission.